# Hide maven build Directory in eclipseJuno/M2e/subclipse

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno, subclipse

I am using Maven3/eclipseJuno/M2e/subclipse. If I run the maven build I got the target directory in each project. When I syn with subclise all the target folder are showing as changed, is there any way to hide the target holder in the svn syn without making it as svn:ignore

Comment: But you *should* mark the target folder with svn:ignore... it's not meant to be checked in

Comment: I preferred Window->Preferences->Team->ignoredResources , in Add Pattern I added target

Comment: Yeah fine, but everyone else in your team then needs to do the same thing. And what if someone's using the command line? Eclipse will respect your svn:ignore settings, which is why you should use it.

Comment: @artbristol I accept your answer but I feel it unnecessary to check-in all my projects[its huge in number]

Answer (score 0):

You can declare any folder (or file) as *derived*. Right-click the resource, go to properties, and enable the derived flag under attributes.

[image]

Comment: I preferred Window->Preferences->Team->ignoredResources , in Add Pattern I added target